# How to retrieve HTML information about specific actions using WebDriver

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to reverse engineer Selenium WebDriver to write my tests for me as I use it. This would entail opening a WebDriver on screen, and clicking around and using it as normal. It will output instructions like `self.driver.find_element_by_id('username-box')` or whatnot for me, instead of the time-wasting of right-clicking the "Inspect element" each time I write a test.

Ideally this will give me a nice xpath which is more exact. How do I retrieve the Xpath/way to recreate actions when manually using Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getAttribute("outerHTML") ; this way you can get HTML counterpart of the element, this might help.

Comment: You're going to be spending a lot more time writing the tool than you'll save by doing it manually, but I guess that's almost the definition of being a programmer. One problem with this idea is that your program wouldn't be able to write the correct xpath, because it doesn't have the context of WHY you want a specific element.  You can get the xpath of an element in the dev tools in Chrome easily enough, but it tends to give you things like "the first div inside the third div inside the element with id X", rather than something more context-specific such as class names and text content.

Comment: ty kushal, that's helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nameless said, it won't solve the "make me an efficient XPath", etc. problem that you are talking about but you can install Selenium IDE (a FF plugin) and record your scenarios and then export them into various languages. It doesn't write the best code but you can get an idea of what it does with a quick download and install.

Comment: SO has some weird ones. I cancelled theirs out